# Burn Bootstrapper does not uninstall chained MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I have a Burn Bootstrapper with 2 MSIs and 2 Exe Packages. My Product MSI does not get uninstalled when I uninstall with the bootstrapper.
relevant Package part from Bundle.wxs

```
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="Resources\MyProduct.msi" ForcePerMachine="yes" Visible="yes" Permanent="no">
```

(the visibility is only set to be able to uninstall "per hand" later on. The install log seems to be alright regarding installation of the product, and it shows (the MSI) in Add/Remove Programs.
(excerpt)

```
    [0020:0D1C][2015-07-15T16:15:50]i201: Planned package: MyProduct.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
    [0B34:0E40][2015-07-15T16:17:43]i305: Verified acquired payload: MyProduct.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\MyProduct.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5147F2CD-4057-408C-9871-5CF419E4A064}v3.14.0000\MyProduct.msi.
    [0B34:0AEC][2015-07-15T16:17:44]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {5147F2CD-4057-408C-9871-5CF419E4A064}, version: 3.14.0000, package: MyProduct.msi
    [0B34:0AEC][2015-07-15T16:17:44]i301: Applying execute package: MyProduct.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5147F2CD-4057-408C-9871-5CF419E4A064}v3.14.0000\MyProduct.msi, arguments: ' ALLUSERS="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" INSTALLBASE="1"'
    [0020:0D1C][2015-07-15T16:23:38]i319: Applied execute package: MyProduct.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
    [0B34:0AEC][2015-07-15T16:23:38]i325: Registering dependency: {973aefce-662d-437a-b703-e6e06af73ea5} on package provider: {5147F2CD-4057-408C-9871-5CF419E4A064}, package: MyProduct.msi
```

on uninstall however the state of the package is always absent, thus not uninstalled. is this a possible bug or am I missing something painfully obvious?
uninstall log excerpt:

```
    [0F30:0EE0][2015-07-15T16:24:48]i101: Detected package: MyProduct.msi, state: Absent, cached: Complete
    [0F30:0EE0][2015-07-15T16:24:49]i201: Planned package: MyProduct.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Unregister
    [0BBC:0FD8][2015-07-15T16:24:50]i326: Removed dependency: {973aefce-662d-437a-b703-e6e06af73ea5} on package provider: {5147F2CD-4057-408C-9871-5CF419E4A064}, package MyProduct.msi
    [0BBC:0FD8][2015-07-15T16:24:50]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {5147F2CD-4057-408C-9871-5CF419E4A064}, package: MyProduct.msi
    [0BBC:0FD8][2015-07-15T16:24:50]i351: Removing cached package: MyProduct.msi, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5147F2CD-4057-408C-9871-5CF419E4A064}v3.14.0000\
```

Tested with a VM and an empty snapshot, to be sure to not have a tainted testing environment. (using WiX 3.8 + wixextba because i need ability to check for two directories listed and a few little checks here and there)

edit: with a fresh head this morning i tried it again, and reread all the logs probably the culprit may be (different guids, new run...)

```
    [0FA0:054C][2015-07-16T10:09:48]w355: Unable to register source directory: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{39A0BA42-7EAB-435C-BADC-C531E5B16763}v3.14.0000\, product: {39A0BA42-7EAB-435C-BADC-C531E5B16763}, reason: 0x80070645. Continuing...
```

i found nothing regarding this error except for problems with Microsoft Security Essentials. Any clues?

edit2: [MSDN Errorcodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376931(v=vs.85).aspx) 1605 is "ERROR_UNKNOWN_PRODUCT" yet the MSI Installation log has no "return value 3" and states

```
    MSI (s) (90:78) [11:06:10:483]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: MyProduct. Product Version: 3.14.0000. Product Language: 1031. Manufacturer: MyManufacturer. Installation success or error status: 0.
```

I can uninstall it when set Visible="yes".

Comment: is there perhaps a mix-up of per machine and per user installations within the bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To whom it may concern;

the problem was, that the MSI/wxs had Id='*'for Product. As soon as I fixed the Productcode (which will be changed for every release to get Major Upgrades) the registration does work and the MSI is properly uninstalled.